# Dialing USSD code generates 'IllegalStateException'

Tags: android, ussd

I wanna transfer money through SIM card Using USSD code..
In instance, for my SIM card, the USSD will Seem like that '*858*2*phonenumber*3#'

**This is my android Code..**

```
String ussd = "*858*000*1" + Uri.encode("#");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(ussd))));
```

I have the permission of `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"` in the manifest.

**Logcat**:

```
10-13 11:43:16.541  16048-16048/com.example.ahmedsharaf.testingthessid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ahmedsharaf.testingthessid, PID: 16048
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3848)
```

Comment: Can you post stack trace?

Comment: Post your logcat and point out the line that the exception is trigger from.